# Save word with offset

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm trying to use `sw` in MIPS to access a spot in an array. The exercise is to take a string, and then increment a list of numbers each time a letter occurs in the string.

```
.data

pos:    .word   0
letter: .word   65
index:  .word   0
buffer: .space  1024
array:  .byte   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
prompt: .asciiz "Enter a string: "
pdng1:  .asciiz ": "    #used to make our output look nice
pdng2:  .asciiz ", "

.text
    ...
    lw  $t0, pos    #position in the string
    la  $t1, array  #holds the array itself
    la  $t2, buffer #holds the buffe
    sw  $t3, letter



loopcp: bgt $t3, 90, looplw #if t is greater than 90, then it is lower case
      lw    $t3, letter #save letter
      subi  $t4, $t3, 65    #$t4 now holds the index in the array that we want to access
      #### ERROR ON LINE BELOW ####
      sw    $t4($t1), index
      addi  index, index, 1 #take what's at the offset we calculated and increment it
      addi  $t0, $t0, 1     #increment the position in the string

      blt   $t0, 256, loopcp
```

I tried using `addi` to go directly to the address in the array, but that didn't work either...  I've been looking up the documentation, but I can't find anything helpful for what I'm doing.

EDIT:
I'm getting an error that reads,:

```
Error in C:\Users\robert\Downloads\Lab7 line 37 column 8: "(": operand is of incorrect type
```

Ideally, it should store the memory address in an array (0-25) where a value is stored that is keeping track of the frequency of the letter loaded in from the statement:

```
      lw    $t3, letter #save letter
```

Comment: It would be useful for your answerers to know what your error is ("that didn't work" doesn't say much). Would you mind including your error in your question, along with the expected behavior?

Comment: @jadhachem I edited it in... sorry, this is pretty basic stuff that should have been there... I hope I was clear enough in the description

Comment: MIPS is a load-store-architecture.You cannot do arithmetic (or any other read-modify-write) on memory locations, all instructions that are not explicitly loads or stores are register-register only.

Comment: @EOF I tried using lines like `addi     $t5, $t4($t1), 1` which also doesn't work. sw was the only way I could think of to get the right address to go to was to look up and store $t4($t1) and I ran into this problem.

Comment: @RobertCrawford: Well, MIPS *also* doesn't have complicated addressing-modes. Sorry, `[16-bit-signed-immediate]($register)` is all the addressing you get.

Comment: @EOF ok, so how does addressing in an array like this work? I can't think of any way that wouldn't involve doing something like this.

Answer (score 1):

Addressing into an array in MIPS:

Say you have the address of the beginning of the array in `$s0`, and you have the index you want to access in `$s1`. The size of the array elements is 4. To access `array[index]`, you do:

```
sll    $t0, $s1, 2          #byte-addressing, needs index*sizeof(element)
add    $t0, $t0, $s0        #calculate array+index*sizeof(element)
lw/sw  $s2, 0($t0)          #load to- or store from register $s2
```

You obviously need the extra temporary register `$t0`.

To increment the value at `array[index]`, you can do this (assuming `$t0` holds `&array[index]`, calculated as shown above:

```
lw     $t1, 0($t0)
addi   $t1, $t1, 1
sw     $t1, 0($t0)
```

Comment: Does this work for outputting too? I tried doing this... it runs, but it gives me an error, `Error in C:\Users\robert\Downloads\Lab7 line 72: Runtime exception at 0x004000e8: fetch address not aligned on word boundary 0x1000fdfd` In the printing loop, I just increment one value each time (in this case, would be $t1)

Comment: Actually, on second thought, what does $s2 stand for? I may have been doing this wrong and it only looks like it works... I haven't gotten it to output correctly, so all I know is that it compiles. I also don't understand how $s2 is related to the array that I'm trying to change.

Comment: @RobertCrawford: 1. MIPS load/store instructions require "natural alignment", meaning the addresses *must be* even multiples of the element size. You *cannot* just increment an address and expect it to be a valid address again. 2. `$s2` is just another register. You could also use a temp register `$tn` for it. It's just the register that gets loaded with the value from the array, or that holds the value you want to store. Seriously, do you not have an instruction set reference?

Comment: I read through it, but maybe I'm just not understanding it quite well enough... but anyway, I understood from how sll works that you can't just go across indexes one at a time. I got that. I figured that $s2 could be just another register, but I wasn't sure. As for my first comment, looking back it is rather unclear, but I was trying to say that I was incrementing the values in `array` not index.

Comment: @RobertCrawford: I've added an example of how to increment a value in an array.

Comment: I followed your advice, and after hours of debugging and trying to make sure it works, and I hit a snag somewhere. I copied your code (obviously with the appropriate registers) the way it was written, but my code doesn't seem to want to increment properly; it just keeps adding to the equivalent $t1, and I don't know (using mars) of a way to see if it's actually updating the list; even if it is it's with with wrong total. Thanks for all of your help so far... I know it's late, but when you're on, if you're still willing to help, do you want me to edit my code into the original question?

Comment: @RobertCrawford: At this point, I'd advise you to write the program in a higher-level language first. C is very easy to hand-compile to assembly, and much easier to reason about and debug.